# Removing last item from a list with cursor adapter not working

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I am developing an android application which display all of a contacts sms messages (actually the contact thread) in listView witch has a cursor adapter to get Sms messages

here is my query to use in adapter:

```
//threadId ==> id of thread which I need it's messages
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"),
    new String[] {"_id", "thread_id" ,"date" ,"body"},"thread_id = ?", new String[] { threadId }, "date ASC");

adapter = new myListAdapter(this, cursor);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_chathistory);
lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is my adapter:

```
public class myListAdapter  extends CursorAdapter
{


    public myListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) 
    {
        boolean autoRequery = true;
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {

        String temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));

        TextView txtMes;

        txtMes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_mess);

        txtMes.setText(temp);

    }



    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Every thing is working well , list will display items correct.
But when I want to delete a message

if the message is first middle item in list it will be deleted well and list will be updated(as auto requery is on) fine , but if I delete last message(both when there is only one message in thread and when there is many message in thread and trying to delete last one) message will be deleted but i got a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` after debugging I find the problem is with requery (when I disable auto requery sms will be deleted without refreshing list , when i call `adapter.getCursor().requery();` i got same exception.

here is my delete code:

```
try
{

    //itemsToDelete ==> a string array containing id of message to be removed(just one message)

    ///////making sure itemsToDelete is correct///////
    String s = "Delete Id: ";
    for (String ss : itemsToDelete )
    {
        s = s + ss+ ",";
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ///////////////////////////////



    int a = getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms" +"/"),"_id" + "=?",itemsToDelete);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+a, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //I don't got any exceptions here , another CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException happens from some where else and cause force close
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery()), you shouldn't be using requery:

> This method was deprecated in API level 11. Don't use this. Just
>   request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update
>   your list view once the new cursor comes back.

I'd follow what the docs suggest here and simply request a new cursor. Once you do that, you can swap it out with the old one by calling `swapCursor()` on a `CursorAdapter`

Comment: I am not using requry , I just enable auto requery on constructor and it's not deprecated.

Comment: I think it is though. The docs: This constant was deprecated in API level 11. This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader.

Comment: Is there any example for LoaderManager and CursorLoader?

Comment: By the way , using swapCursor() did not fixed anything :(

Comment: can you post what you have now that you're using swap cursor